# What causes this to show Unicode as garbage characters?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Yesterday I moved my site to a new hosting server and I'm having trouble with Unicode text.

In old hosting package same script works fine and In new hosting, Unicode showing as below:

[image]

In both hosting this is the test code I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<?

$host = '';
$user = '';
$pass = '';
$db = '';

$con = mysql_connect($host , $user , $pass) or die ("Connection could not established." .mysql_error() );

mysql_select_db($db , $con)  or die ("Colud not select database" . mysql_error());

$sql = "select * from news_line where status='enable' order by date DESC";
$res = mysql_query($sql);


while($dat=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
  echo $dat['news'];
}
mysql_close($con); 

?>

</body>
</html>
```

What may cause this behavior in new hosting?

Comment: You're using the term ‘*Unicode*’ as if it was a character encoding. [It's not.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: why are you writing php code with code snippet ?

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things that can cause your encoding to break like this. Unicode in itself isn't a character encoding, though, I'm guessing you're talking about UTF-8 encoding (as this is what you tried with your HTML header?).

So, it's important that your entire pipeline of code has the same charset. If it's different, you may get unexpected results, like you are now. A general idea of what you need to think of is

- HTML header
- PHP header
- MySQL connection
- Databases/tables
- Your actual `.php` file

---

You already set your HTML header, with

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

But that doesn't account for the data PHP sends, so you also need

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

And this line should be placed *before* **any** kind of output (put it at the top of your file).

Next, we need to check the connection. You're using the old, outdated `mysql_` API, so then you'd need

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

after creating your MySQL connection (typical would be after `mysql_select_db()`).

As for your databases and tables, you need to know that collation is not the same as charset. However, both should be UTF-8, and you can set it with running these queries in SQL

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Lastly, it might also be needed for the file itself to be UTF-8 encoded. If you're using Notepad++ to write your code, this can be done in the "Format" drop-down on the taskbar. You should use `UTF-8 w/o BOM` (see [What's different between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223926/4535200)).

## Note:

Any data already stored in the database will not necessarily have this encoding, so if there are broken characters in your database, and you go through with all these steps, your content might need to be re-uploaded to the database with your proper encoding (just submit the content again). There are methods to do this in batches if you have a lot of data. Although I've never used it myself, I've heard people succesfully using [Force UTF8](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8), but like I said, I've never used it myself.

---

Footnotes:

Your code is using a very outdated API, and I highly recommend you look into either MySQLi or PDO. Should you do so, make sure to use **prepared statements** on anything that deals with variables.

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated since PHP 5.5 (and **removed entirely** in PHP 7) and you should [stop using them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942) if you can. You should choose another API that allows you to use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) (which you *really should* when dealing with variables), like `mysqli_*` or PDO 
- see [choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

---

You could also have a look at

- [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)